# How to find the list of characters that not included in allowed regex using TSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex, t-sql

I have regex with allowed symbols

`0-9a-zA-Z\u00C0-\u00D6\u00D8-\u00F6\u00F8-\u017E\u0192\u1e9e\u00b0\u00aa\u00ba\u03bc\u03b1\u03b2\u03c0\u03bb\u03b3\u03b4\u00b2\u00b3\u00bc\u00bd\u00be\u2154\u00a9\u00a7\u00a1\u00a2\u00ae\u00b1\u00d7\u02dc\u2122\uffeb\u00b9\u2082 ()\[\]{}<>.,/'%!#|_&+:@^=$€¥£*;~"?\r\n\\-`

and `PersonEntity` table which has `fullBiography` field.

The task is to detect list of symbols that contain `fullBiography` field and not included in regex.

I started with the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM PersonEntity
WHERE FullBiography NOT LIKE '%[0-9a-zA-Z\u00C0-\u00D6\u00D8-\u00F6\u00F8-\u017E\u0192\u1e9e\u00b0\u00aa\u00ba\u03bc\u03b1\u03b2\u03c0\u03bb\u03b3\u03b4\u00b2\u00b3\u00bc\u00bd\u00be\u2154\u00a9\u00a7\u00a1\u00a2\u00ae\u00b1\u00d7\u02dc\u2122\uffeb\u00b9\u2082 ()\[\]{}<>.,/''%!#|_&+:@^=$€¥£*;~"?\r\n\\-]%';
```

But it does not solve my problem.

Any thoughts on how could I retrieve not allowed chars?

Comment: Try use:  `WHERE FullBiography NOT LIKE N'%[0-9a-zA-Z\u00C0-\u00D6\u00D8-\u00F6\u00F8-\u017E\u0192\u1e9e\u00b0\u00aa\u00ba\u03bc\u03b1\u03b2\u03c0\u03bb\u03b3\u03b4\u00b2\u00b3\u00bc\u00bd\u00be\u2154\u00a9\u00a7\u00a1\u00a2\u00ae\u00b1\u00d7\u02dc\u2122\uffeb\u00b9\u2082 ()\[\]{}<>.,/''%!#|_&+:@^=$€¥£*;~"?\r\n\\-]%'`

Comment: You'll need to handle wildcard characters in the pattern [this way](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#using-wildcard-characters-as-literals), or add an [escape clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#pattern-matching-with-the-escape-clause) to make the usual wildcard characters part of the pattern. I think you also need to convert all of the Unicode code points into something line `... + NChar( 0x00C0 ) + ...`.

Comment: Could you add some dummy data and your desired result?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find the string which has at least one character other than the listed ones, you should approach it from the other direction:

```
SELECT *
FROM PersonEntity
WHERE FullBiography LIKE '%[^0-9a-zA-Z\u00C0-\u00D6\u00D8-\u00F6\u00F8-\u017E\u0192\u1e9e\u00b0\u00aa\u00ba\u03bc\u03b1\u03b2\u03c0\u03bb\u03b3\u03b4\u00b2\u00b3\u00bc\u00bd\u00be\u2154\u00a9\u00a7\u00a1\u00a2\u00ae\u00b1\u00d7\u02dc\u2122\uffeb\u00b9\u2082 ()\[\]{}<>.,/''%!#|_&+:@^=$€¥£*;~"?\r\n\\-]%';
```

Please note the not operator (`^`) at the beginning of the character list.

This basically says: Find me a the string which has a character at any position which does not match with any of the listed ones.

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues. The first is creating a pattern for `like` that includes Unicode characters. As the following query demonstrates Unicode code points are not supported in the string literal:

```
select
  case when N'4' like NChar(0x0034) then 'Yes' else 'No' end as [NChar],
  case when N'4' like N'\u0034' then 'Yes' else 'No' end as [\u],
  case when N'4' like N'0x0034' then 'Yes' else 'No' end as [0x];
```

Note that other `RegEx` escaped "characters", e.g. `'\r'` and `'\n'`, don't exist and need to be replaced by the appropriate `NChar` values.

The second issue is that the pattern contains `like` wildcard characters: `'%'`, `'_'`, `'['`,  `']'` and `'^'`. They need to be escaped as explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#using-wildcard-characters-as-literals). Again, the `RegEx` rules for escaping characters don't apply.